# Acceso denegado. Problemón al iniciar phpmyadmin

Tags: php, html, mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp

Cuando inicio Apache y despues inicio Mysql, no hay ningun problema. Pero cuando luego doy a admin y entra a phpmyadmin me dice acceso denegado. Antes no me daba ningun problema. Hee buscado en Google y he probado distintas soluciones como poner contraseña o cambiar algo del archivo config.ini.php pero nada. Dejo abajo una foto de lo que me aparece. ¿Cómo lo puedo solucionar? ¿Qué puedo hacer? Muchas gracias.
PD:Lo he conseguido arreglar durante dos dias de las siguiente forma.  Pero después vuelve a aparecer el error a los dos días, por lo que no se ha arreglado del todo.
Cambie el nombre de la carpeta mysql / data a mysql / data_old (puede usar cualquier nombre)
Crea una nueva carpeta mysql / data
Copie el contenido que reside en mysql / backup a la nueva carpeta mysql / data
Cambie el nombre de la carpeta mysql / data a mysql / data_old (puede usar cualquier nombre)
Crea una nueva carpeta mysql / data
Copie el contenido que reside en mysql / backup a la nueva carpeta mysql / data
Copie todas las carpetas de su base de datos que están en mysql / data_old a mysql / data (omitiendo las carpetas mysql, performance_schema y phpmyadmin de data_old)
Finalmente copie el archivo ibdata1 de mysql / data_old y reemplácelo dentro de la carpeta mysql / data
Inicie MySQL desde el panel de control de XAMPP

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Segun indica el primer mensaje de error (empezando por abajo) tienes que revisar el archivo `config.inc.php` y comprobar si has puesto bien la toda la información necesaria para la conexion.

Comment: @masterguru ¿Y que tiene que poner? No tengo contraseña y el resto creo que esta bien. Además lo puedo solucionar durante un par de días de una forma que vi en internet. Lo pongo en la publicacion editada. Pero a los dos dias vuelve a dar el error.

Comment: Prueba en **config.inc.php**: `[auth_type] = 'cookie'` y si le pusiste una contraseña, tambien: `[AllowNoPassword] = false`. De esta forma siempre pide el usuario y password del root para entrar.

Answer (score 1):

Revisa bien el `username` y `contraseña` y que este `usuario` tenga `permisos` para usar la base de datos.

Comment: ¿Donde puedo revisar eso? ¿En algún archivo, en configuración? Muchas gracias.

Comment: si estas usando xampp, en config .init algo asi croe que se llama

Comment: @sybot ¿Y que tiene que poner? No tengo contraseña y el resto creo que esta bien. Además lo puedo solucionar durante un par de días de una forma que vi en internet. Lo pongo en la publicacion editada. Pero a los dos dias vuelve a dar el error.

Comment: @sybot Creo que esta todo bien

Answer (score 1):

Como dices que no tienes contraseña comprueba que tienes el parámetro AllowNoPassword del archivo config.ini.php activado de esta forma:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true;
```

Comment: Está asi sí. Y nada. Pero gracias

Comment: Pues quizas una reinstalación del phpmyadmin es lo que se tercia ahora, vamos, a saber la de cambios que ya habras probado para arreglarlo y como estará todo ahora.  Si entras con el cliente de terminal entras bien con el root?  Ponte como root, escribe `mysql` y mira si te pregunta por contraseña... si no te pregunta quizas si exista igualmente y la tienes en el archivo /root/.mycnf o algo asi (no recuerdo ahora el nombre)